# What is the common way of showing that infinite series is holomorphic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, absolute-convergence

I saw frequently in some literature that "function is absolutely convergent and uniformly bounded so it is holomorphic" but I don't understand how this follows. Generally in number theory, how does one show that infinite series is holomorphic?

The only theorem I know is the following one

If $\{f_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions that converges uniformly to a function $f$ in every compact subset of $\Omega$, then $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$.

Also, I have Morera's Theorem, for which I'm not quite sure how I should use in practice.

Would someone give me an insight or point out a relevant theorem?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? – Btw, a *series* can be absolutely convergent, not a function.

Comment: This has nothing to do with number theory.

Comment: Cauchy estimates usually give angled way to those kinds of things.

Comment: If you're talking about a series then Morera can be pretty useful if you can apply dominated convergence (or fubini's theorem). We want to show $0 = \int_\gamma f dx = \int \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f_i dx$. If we can switch the limit and the intergral, we get that this equals $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \int f_i dx$, which can be easier to calculate/reason about.

Comment: why do you close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you typed your sentence correctly, or not, but here's my attempt at a best guess regarding what you might have meant.

Morera's Theorem is  good start. Now suppose you have a sequence of holomorphic functions $\{g_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ all defined on some open set $\Omega\subset \Bbb{C}$.

For each $k$, let $f_k=g_1+\dots +g_k$ be the $k^{th}$ partial sum. If you can show somehow that there is an $f:\Omega\to\Bbb{C}$ such that $f_k\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$, then by the theorem you mention, it follows that $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_n$ is holomorphic.

Now, how do we show that the partial sums of a sequence of functions converges uniformly? Well, the simplest and most classical test is the Weierstrass M-test, which in great generality says the following:

> Let $A$ be any non-empty set (doesn't even have to be a subset of $\Bbb{C}$), and let $V$ be a Banach space (eg $\Bbb{C}$). Given a sequence of functions $\{g_n:A\to V\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, let $M_n:=\sup\limits_{z\in A}|g_n(z)|_V$. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n<\infty$ then the partial sums $\left\{\sum_{k=1}^ng_k\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge absolutely and uniformly.

In short, this says "normal convegrence/convergence in supremum norm implies absolute and uniform convergence". So, if you combine the Weirstrass M-test and that theorem you know and apply it to each compact subset of $\Omega$, it gives you a simple way of checking that a series of holomorphic functions is again holomorphic.